# AWS Amplify fails to create models in the cloud after adding Analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-regions

Currently my amplify project has the `API`, `Authentication`, `File Storage` and `Functions` categories. Everything works perfectly fine until I add `Analytics`!

I am having the following error when I add `analytics` to my amplify project in react native and try to push GraphQL changes by performing `amplify push`:

`Failed to create models in the cloud: Modelgen job creation failed`

Everything is actually on the same `AWS-Region`, which is us-east-1.

Many suggests on the web that it's an issue that comes from the credentials that I am using, I verified numerous times and it is not, my amplify credentials and config file are perfectly matching AWS credentials. My `aws_access_key_id`, `aws_secret_access_key` and `region` from the credentials and config file are aligned with amplify user.

I also verified my user IAM permissions, and it has the following one :

- `AdministratorAccess`
- `AdministratorAccess-Amplify`
- `AmazonMobileAnalyticsFullAccess`

When I revert my changes, by removing `Analytics` from my project using `amplify remove analytics` I am not having that error anymore when I push GraphQL changes.

Anyone has an idea what could be causing this error?